# Terraform works on some AWS regions and fails on others

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm new to Terraform so I may be missing something, but I did quiet a research and I didnt find a solution. We have companies AWS account with somw instances running already on region eu-west-1. I decided to test Terraform so we can start using it. I created IAM user with appropriate permissions and made this tf file:

```
resource "aws_instance" "test" {
    ami           = "ami-21abf052"
    instance_type = "t2.small"
}
```

`terraform apply` failed with the following error:

```
* aws_instance.test: Error launching source instance: timeout while waiting for state to become 'success' (timeout: 15s)
```

At first I thought it's the credentials problem, so I tried running the same from awscli:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-21abf052 --count 1 --instance-type t2.small
```

It worked like a charm.
After that I tried many things including: using different IAM user, changing the permissions (giving "Allow" to ec2:*), using different AMIs, setting different VPCs, setting names, tags, different instance types, hardcoding the access_key and secret_key in .tf file, setting the region explicitly in the file (for awscli the default is eu-west-1). Anything I was doing the awscli was working and terraform failing.

After loosing one day I tried in region eu-central-1 and it just worked.

Am my missing something? Should I somehow add permissions for regions separately? Isn't awscli using the same ~/.aws/credentials file if I don't define it in .tf file?

aha, my current permissions in AWS:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "sts:GetCallerIdentity",
                "iam:ListRoles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:
I tested more regions:

- us-west-1 works
- us-east-1 fails
- sa-east-1 works

My AMIs:

```
variable "amis" {
    default = {
        eu-west-1 = "ami-21abf052"
        eu-central-1 = "ami-b0db1ddf"
        us-east-1 = "ami-e6d5d2f1"
        us-west-1 = "ami-bcb9eedc"
        sa-east-1 = "ami-ec811880"
    }
}
```

And versions `Terraform v0.7.13 aws-cli/1.11.28 Python/2.7.12+ Linux/4.8.0-30-generic botocore/1.4.85`

Comment: Forgot to mention:
Terraform v0.7.13
aws-cli/1.11.28 Python/2.7.12+ Linux/4.8.0-30-generic botocore/1.4.85

Comment: Are you changing the AMI id for each region?

Comment: Yes, I use AMI from the appropriate region.. Today I will check other regions (US etc) to check how it is there

Comment: How long does it take until you get the time out in terraform? The error message says it's only 15s?
Do you have a direct connection to the internet or is there maybe a proxy in between, which is configured for your AWS CLI, but not in terraform (provider)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried instance types other than t2.small? Sometimes the region/AZ run out of specific instance types. In my experience, the instances fail to launch because AWS simply exceeded capacity. Most notably:

- t2 instances in general
- t2.small
- eu regions

So the problem yo are seeing may not be related to Terraform. Try some other instance type (like `m3.medium` or `m4.large`) to rule out Terraform.

Also see: [Error: InsufficientInstanceCapacity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-capacity.html). The fact CLI was able to launch could be one instance was available at that time.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the idea. Before I was trying t2.micro and t2.small and both failed. Now I tried m3.medium and m4.large and still the same. Also if the would run out of instances the awscli should also fail. I still think it's some problem with configuration on AWS, but can't figure out what